# How to pass a parameter to --world-parameters or npm run command to be consumed by scripts in package

Tags: javascript, npm, testcafe, cucumberjs, npm-scripts

I know that this question could be a duplicate of many similar existing questions however, still want to ask more precisely for help in the scenario I want to understand:

I am using [this](https://github.com/rquellh/testcafe-cucumber) repo in my example and I have following script block in my package.json

I need to pass one parameter from the command line to identify the environment in which I wish to test, for example something like:

```
-- testEnv=staging
```

How can I update the following script blcok to accomodate this change.

I have already tried to set different configurations for world parameter like this:

```
 --world-parameters \"{\\\"environment\\\": \\\"Dev\\\"}\"
```

however it is now confusing to maintain various version of world parameter configs hence looking to use command line to send variable values through.

```
"scripts": {
             "test-chrome": "./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js.cmd --tags @Run --format json:./testlab/support/reports/report.json",
}
```

Comment: Integration with TestCafe that you used supports not all the features and possibilities of Cucumber.js. 
Would you please clarify how you want to use the specified environment in the test code?

Comment: All i am looking to use the passed parameter value in the script so that i can use the value to pick the appropriate url for testing. Or if there is any other way i can use the passing of command line parameter in conjunction with the above script, that should be helpful

Answer (score 1):

TestCafe allows you to use [environment variables](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/access-environment-variables-in-tests.html), and have a config.json file to store the baseUrl:

So, you could do

```sh
export testEnv=staging
npm run test-chrome
```

Then enter that value as part of your config [file](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/faq/#how-do-i-work-with-configuration-files-and-environment-variables).

```
{
    baseUrl: process.env.testEnv
}
```

Or, if you want a default baseUrl, you could have a helper class that just returns `const targetUrl = process.env.testEnv || config.baseUrl`.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with [version 1.20.0](https://testcafe.io/404002/release-notes/framework/2022-7-18-testcafe-v1-20-0-released#global-starting-url), TestCafe offers a way to specify the base url for test pages in all interfaces:

- [CLI](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402639/reference/command-line-interface#--base-url)
- Program API [`runner.run({baseUrl})`](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402655/reference/testcafe-api/runner/run#baseurl)
- [Config file](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402638/reference/configuration-file#baseurl)